# Cannot convert a string array to string

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have created an string array `String[] arr` to hold all the content from my files:

```
String[] contentarr=file.openfile();
```

Later when I try to convert this string array back to string with:

```
String contentstr=Arrays.toString(contentarr);
```

it keeps giving me the error `arr` cannot be resolved as a variable. Any clue why is that?

UPDATED code (learning Java week 1. Trying to follow some tutorial online but not sure how to fix this error):

```
package readText;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FileData {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String file_path1 = "F:\\CampusImages.txt";
        String file_path2 = "F:\\CampusImageIDs.txt";

        try{
            ReadFileLocal file = new ReadFileLocal(file_path1);
            String[] aryLines = file.openFile(); //Already wrote openFile function in another file.

            int i;
            for (i=0; i<aryLines.length; i++){
                System.out.println(aryLines[i]);
            }       
        }

        catch(IOException e) { 
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
        }


        String all=Arrays.toString(aryLines);  //ERROR: aryLines cannot be resolved as a variable.
        WriteFile content = new WriteFile( file_path2, true);
        content.WriteToFile("Write from here: ");
        System.out.println(content);  // Also, is the writing part code right?
        }
}
```

Comment: Is the variable still in scope?

Comment: post the code that give you the error, not the one that you have modified

Comment: Post your whole class please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arylines is not in scope.

```
    String file_path1 = "F:\\CampusImages.txt";
    String file_path2 = "F:\\CampusImageIDs.txt";
    String[] arylines;           

    try{
        ReadFileLocal file = new ReadFileLocal(file_path1);
        aryLines = file.openFile(); 

        int i;
        for (i=0; i<aryLines.length; i++){
            System.out.println(aryLines[i]);
        }       
    }

    catch(IOException e) { 
        System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
    }


    String all=Arrays.toString(aryLines);  //now arylines is resolved
    WriteFile content = new WriteFile( file_path2, true);
    content.WriteToFile("Write from here: ");
    System.out.println(content);  // Also, is the writing part code righ
```